# Android: Drawing shapes programmatically on a View in layout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view, shapes

The documentation about this is really confusing. I simply need to add rectangels to a View I defined in my main.xml layout file. It will be a small part of the layout.

What I want to achieve is, I want to add shelves to a room but since the room shape and shelves change, I need to add them programmatically.

Below is a little part of my main.xml file, you can see the View I defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="650dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/getDirections"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/roomplan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the custom View class I created to handle dynamic changes:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    ShapeDrawable roomFrame;
    ArrayList<ShapeDrawable> shelfFrames;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        roomFrame.draw(canvas);
        for (ShapeDrawable shelfFrame : shelfFrames){
            shelfFrame.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void setRoom(Stage stage){
        roomFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        roomFrame.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);   
        roomFrame.setBounds(10, 10, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
    }

    public void setShelves(ArrayList<Shelf> shelves){
        shelfFrames = new ArrayList<ShapeDrawable>();
        for(int i = 0; i<shelves.size(); i++){
            ShapeDrawable shelfFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            shelfFrame.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
            shelfFrame.setBounds(shelves.get(i).getXPosition(), shelves.get(i).getYPosition(), shelves.get(i).getWidth(), shelves.get(i).getHeight());
            shelfFrames.add(shelfFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Now simply, when a new room plan is asked I am trying to assign this class to the View object in the xml layout:

```
public void loadRoomPlan(Room room, ArrayList<Shelf> shelves){
    CustomView asdsView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.roomplan);
    asdsView.setRoom(room);
    asdsView.setShelves(shelves);
    asdsView.invalidate();
}
```

I always get

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to org.example.myproject.CustomView

error.

Probably I am doing this very very wrong, am I not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in this line:

```
CustomView asdsView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.shopplan);
```

What is `shopplan`? In case it is a mistake and you meant `R.id.roomplan` try to subtitute the View in your layout for your Custom view:

```
<org.example.myproject.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/roomplan"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Try adding the other two constructors to your `CustomView` class:

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

When you use a custom view in an xml layout, your view has to deal with the layout attributes (the constructor AttributeSet param).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. _shopplan_ is a typo. I edited it to _roomplan_ .

Now I get the error:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class org.example.myproject.CustomView

Comment: See the update. It is dificult to say if it is the best way, but if you get what you need, it is a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: OMG it worked! Thank you very much! Finally, can you please give me some further reading about this? I mean, what is this I am doing here? Is this Drawables? The documentation about this points me to some samples in the SDK but they are very complicated. I guess this is the documentation of it: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Comment: No, this is not a drawable. Your are creating your own custom view from scratch. A View is a user interface object to interact with (like TextViews, Buttons, etc...) A Drawable is some kind of graphic entity (like an image (bitmap), a shape, etc...). In your case your are using drawables to draw your View.

Comment: Thank you very very much! You are the savior of the day.

Comment: Xavi can you please take a look at this one please? [Android: onTouch + onDraw for custom view goes crazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958414/android-ontouch-ondraw-for-custom-view-goes-crazy). I think it is similar to this one in here. Thanks in advamce.